# Compile Error on CodeBlocks with C++ obj/Release/MyApplication.o: no such file or directory under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm new with C++ and also with CodeBlocks; what I'm trying to do is a simple frame with wxwidgets which holds a button inside and test some events.

The compiler outputs the following error:

```
**=== Build: Release in Prueba (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)===
error: obj/Release/PruebaApp.o: No such file or directory
error: obj/Release/PruebaMain.o: No such file or directory
error: no input files
=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s)), second(s) ===**
```

Help, please!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you able to compile other programs, for example a single file project?

Comment: No, I'm not able to. The same error takes place even with a simple "Hello World" test programme.

Comment: Looks like your compiler does not compile the files. It should compile every cpp file -> o file. There is probably something wrong in the settings. This could help: https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/FAQ-Compiling_(errors)#Q:_How_do_I_troubleshoot_a_compiler_problem.3F

Comment: @Alberto, did you build wxWidgets? Are you able to build `minimal ` sample provided with the library?

Comment: @Igor, yes, I built wxWidgets but I cannot manage to make it work within Codeblocks. I have been able to execute a simple app with a window via Linux terminal (outside codeblocks) and it runs correctly. However, I still haven't figured out how to run a simple console programme within codeblocks. I have been a Linux user for several years and I believe CodeBlocks is, if not the best, the most popular IDE you can use under Linux. But I'm seriously considering other options, simply because CodeBlocks is taking too much time from me and I'm not really going anywhere with it.

Comment: @Alberto, so you build wxWidgets yourself and you are able to build and execute `minimal` sample provided with the library. Now, what type of project did you create inside C::B? It does have a project template to use with wxWidgets - you just need to know and match the library build with the option inside the IDE. Also - did you look at https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47231.

Comment: Are you running the standard package or the flatpak?  There are many issues with  the flatpak and I could never actually get it to do anything, but I don't remember if the problems I had were the ones your describing.  If your running the standard package, you also need the contrib package.

Comment: I'm running codeblocks that I downloaded and installed from Ubuntu's repositories (20.04). I had no idea there was a contrib package, though. I'll give it a try. Thank you!